# Main panel grounding

Tags: electrical-panel, subpanel

I have installed a 200 Amp meter upgraded from the old 60 amp and then installed a 200 disconnect with a breaker type switch inside then feeding 200 amp main panel.  My question is do I bond neutral and ground together in the disconnect then run a separate ground to the panel and keep neutrals separate in that panel box and treat it like a sub panel or leave them unbonded in the disconnect and bond them in the panel?

Comment: Is your 200A panel a *main breaker* panel or a *main lug* panel? Are you correct in saying the 200A disconnect is inside, in addition to the 200A panel being inside?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  Does that make a difference?   I believe once you are downstream from a disconnect of any sort, everything needs to be treated as a sub-panel with the neutral and ground isolated.   I recently helped my son on the wiring on his house which included a 200 amp generator transfer switch between the meter and his main panel. We treated the main panel as a sub-panel and it passed inspection just fine.  So I'm curious about main-lug vs. main breaker that you mentioned.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson -- there are some provisions in current Codes that allow for a not-a-service disconnect to be placed between the meter base and the service disconnect

Comment: the disconnect is directly under the meter so I could turn off for a generator and the what was originally a main panel is inside the home located in the basement we are going to move it to outside the stair well for better access but it will still be inside the home.  I hope this helps

Comment: @AndrewBrown -- does this "disconnect" have an *interlock* on it to prevent it from being turned on at the same time as the generator breaker is turned on?

Comment: no just a 200 amp breaker that is manual

Comment: @AndrewBrown -- what make and model is your generator? Also, what all are you interested in running off of it? There are a couple things that need to be fixed here...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel well as of now i dont have one since my ex wife took it when she cleaned out the house but i had a 7500 which i used and it would power about everything in the house as long as the well was not running or the hot water heater and what needs to be fixed?

Comment: @AndrewBrown -- mostly getting you to a way of hooking up the generator that can't accidentally backfeed the grid at 2AM in the dark and rain

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel that is not an issue as when that did happen it just trips out the genny however it was just a portable so on my way out to start it I would just throw the breaker and start it.  I just wanted to make sure that when I wire my new breaker box that I would be within code by separating the grounds and neutrals

Comment: @AndrewBrown -- what all do you want to run off your generator? That's the biggest question here -- are you OK with just backing up the well pump and some outlets/lights that are determined when you put things in, or are there other things that you want/need backed up as well?

Comment: This question should have the generator details edited into it otherwise the answer is nonsensical if the comments get trimmed

Answer (score 2):

### You need a proper *transfer switch* in order to legally and safely use that generator

Your first order of business here is to throw away the suicide cord (after chopping it into pieces that is) and get a proper inlet box, generator cord, and most importantly, a proper *transfer switch* for your application, so that you don't get blamed for a fried linesman, or written up for a blatant Code violation for that matter.

In your situation, especially considering that you are going to be going generator shopping, you will also have to deal with the *other* point many people who put generator setups in get snagged on; namely, neutral/ground bonding.  You see, most portable generators come from the factory with neutral and ground bonded together, so they can be safely and legally used for portable power applications, such as those found on jobsites.  However, the service disconnect sitting on the outside of your house *also* has a neutral-ground bond inside it, and putting the two bonds in parallel causes current to flow places it's not supposed to go.

As a result, most residential (portable generator) transfer applications require a transfer switch/panel with a *switched neutral*, so that the generator's bond and the house's bond are kept separate.  Fortunately, there are a few transfer panels out there that can provide a switched neutral alongside the other conveniences one comes to expect from a transfer switch.  Most notable among them would be the Reliance Controls XRK models from their Panel/Link X series, as they can legally take most (GE THQL being the only exception) 1" breakers, and can be ordered through a variety of dealers (including online sellers) for a reasonable price.  If your existing 200A subpanel uses 3/4" breakers (CH or QO), then you may wish to look at other options, though.  Eaton makes a switching-neutral CH transfer panel (the CH10GEN50xxSN parts) that matches existing CH panels, and while Square-D doesn't make a single product that's directly suitable, they do make the requisite parts needed to field-fabricate such a transfer panel from a suitable QO loadcenter.

### Once you get that transfer switch in...

Once you get a suitable transfer switch in, we can then move onto grounding and bonding considerations as part of the installation of both your subpanel *and* the transfer switch, which in all likelihood will be treated as a subpanel of your indoor subpanel (which is fine).  In both cases, you'll be running 4 wires (hot, hot, neutral, ground) from the power source (disconnect to subpanel, subpanel to transfer switch) to the destination, and leaving the bonding means (bonding screw or bonding strap) out when you reach said destination.  Furthermore, you'll also need to run a 4-wire feed from the *inlet box* over to the transfer switch, just like you were running a feeder to a subpanel as described above.